# how to control each element independently in *ngFor in Angular2?

Tags: angular, ngfor

How can I control clrTreeNodeLoading state of each element independently?
In this example if I change this.loading flag in controller it will affect all tree nodes, but I wanted to change this flag only for selected nodes.

```
<clr-tree>
  <clr-tree-node
    *ngFor="let dir of directories"
    [clrTreeNodeLoading]="loading">
    {{dir.name}}
  </clr-tree-node>
</clr-tree>
```

I thought about generating variable dynamically with index, so I can reference selected flag, but it of course won't work :)

```
<clr-tree>
 <clr-tree-node
   *ngFor="let dir of directories; let i = index"
   [clrTreeNodeLoading]="loading" + i>
   {{dir.name}}
 </clr-tree-node>
</clr-tree>
```

I also have to add that I can't change definition of clr-tree-node, because it is from external framework called 'clarity design system'.

Comment: where is the changing flag defined? is it a property of directories?

Comment: oh thanks you gave me a hint. I will add this property to directories and it should work.

Comment: can I post that as my answer?

Comment: yes. Thank you :)